# JFormFieldList in Frontend -> Notice: Array to string conversion

Tags: jform, form

I'm facing a strange problem. I'm trying to define a custom field for the **frontend**-view of my component like this:

```
defined('JPATH_BASE') or die;

jimport('joomla.form.formfield');
jimport('joomla.form.helper');
JFormHelper::loadFieldClass('list');

class JFormFieldAssignToUser extends JFormFieldList
{
    protected $type = 'assigntouser';

    protected function getInput() 
    {
        $html   = array();
        $user   = JFactory::getUser();           
        $html[] = JHtml::_('select.option', "Test", "Test");                            
        $html   = array_merge(parent::getOptions(), $html);
        return $html;
    }
}
```

now I'm adding this to my xml:

```
<field name        = "assigntouser" 
       type        = "assigntouser"    
       label       = "TEST"                
       description = "TEST"
       filter      = "safehtml"
       default     = "">
    <option value = "">TEST</option>
</field>
```

and include it to my layout like that:

```
<?php echo $this->form->renderFieldset("testfieldset"); ?>
```

But it only shows this error:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/web1/htdocs/layouts/joomla/form/renderfield.php on line 35

A field, which is designed in the same way, that is added to the **backend** of Joomla, works without problems...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to use use `getOptions(..)` not `getInput(...)` with a `JFormFieldList`.

`getInput` returns the full `<select />` input as a string. `getOptions` populates the select options with an array of `<option />` strings.